# Getting "UnauthorizedAccessException" in a BackgroundWorker without accessing UI thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I'm doing some heavy work on a backgroundworker, so that it doesn't affect my Silverlight UI thread. However, in the DoWork function I'm getting this exception:

`UnauthorizedAccessException` "Invalid cross-thread access".

I know I can't access the UI thread from the BackgroundWorker, However, this exception occurs on this line:

```
  ListBoxItem insert = new ListBoxItem();
```

How is that accessing my ui thread??

Here's the actual piece of code I've narrowed it down to. I'm basically doing work creating listboxitems which i'd like to insert to the `sourceList` listbox:

```
void FillSourceList()
{
    busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
        {
            List<ListBoxItem> x = new List<ListBoxItem>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++ )
            {
                ListBoxItem insert = new ListBoxItem(); //<---Getting exception here
                insert.Content = "whatever";
                x.Add(insert);
            }
            args.Result = x;
        };
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            foreach (ListBoxItem insert in (List<ListBoxItem>)(args.Result))
                sourceList.Items.Add(insert);
            busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
        };

    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `ListBoxitem` derives from Control so it is considered part of the GUI. I would have expected a 'detached' item to be OK in a thread too but apparently it isn't.

The obvious solution: build up a list `x` of Content (strings) and delay the creation of the Items to the Completed event.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it seems a bit unecessary for that not to be OK but interesting nonetheless. I do some other processing on the `ListBoxItem`s based on the content, such as coloring, so I can't simply create strings.. however, I suppose I'll manage packing the information I need into a KeyValuePair or something until their creation.

Comment: You could consider a mini ViewModel for the items. Just bind a list to the ItemsSource and you're set, thread-safety included.

Comment: Good idea! I'll probably do that, shouldn't require too many changes for the rest of the project (I hope;).

Comment: @HenkHolterman I would think that as long as the list is bound to a control via ItemsSource, modifying the list would still result in "Invalid cross-thread access" as soon as the databinding propagates the changes to the control. Are you sure that would solve the problem?

Comment: @OliverWeichhold - The Completed event runs on the GUI thread.